# On Huawei Android devices with a fingerprint scanner createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent() does not allow fingerprint unlock

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, huawei-mobile-services, keyguardlock

When using KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent() on Huawei device which have a fingerprint scanner (eg. P9), the screen only works with PIN/Password but does not allow unlock with the fingerprint scanner. On most other brands that works. 
Is this a known issue? I could not find any Stack Overflow entry. Is this problem known to Huawei?

I know I could use the Fingerprint API, but this method works already from Android 5.0 onwards and is not restricted to fingerprint.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find out what you had to do? @mikegr

Comment: Hoping you might come back with how you solved this?  I'm running into this same issue now.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem